# Sorting the DIGIT of a number LIke Number = 584 and its output as Sorted_number= 458

Tags: java

```
    public class SortingNumber {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                int number = 845, temp=0, sorted_number=0;
                while (number>0){
                    temp = number%10;
                    if(temp < sorted_number){
                        sorted_number = temp;
                        System.out.println(sorted_number);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(temp);
                    }
                    number /= 10;
                }
            }
        }
```

I have write some code but it is not working. Please tell any simple code for sorting the digit of the number WITHOUT ANY METHODS.

Comment: Hint: you can use "counting sort" for this.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/

Comment: How? Can you tell me ?

Comment: Use counting sort on the digits of the number.  How?  You write code.  Seriously, this looks like a homework exercise, and you will learn NOTHING by having us do your homework for you.

Comment: I can advise. We know that there are only 10 digits. Just create an array of 10 elements int[] array = new int[10]; then when You get digit do a array[digit] ++, now the array index - digit, array value - count (how many times digit present in number). Just iterate over array and print every index as may times as the array[index] value

Comment: Can you start with writing all 4s you find in the number?

Comment: If your tutor is telling you to solve problems "without any methods", you should probably be looking for a different course.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple code snippet for your problem. Similar to @Maxim's solution.

```
public static void sort(int number){
    int[] arr = new int[10];
    int temp = 0;
    while (number>0){
        temp = number%10;
        arr[temp] = arr[temp]+1;
        number /= 10;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

        if(arr[i] !=0) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= arr[i]; j++)
                System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting this : arr[temp] = arr[temp]+1;

Comment: Have you tried this solution. arr[temp] = arr[temp]+1; Its for repetitive digit like 122 or 545 to solve this problem we need to count the presence of that number.